# How To Nudge the Position of Vertices Randomly, in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a geometric shape but I would like to make it more 'natural' shaped (like a crystal).  My solution is to nudge the vertices slightly in random directions (along each vertice's local axis), so all the sides become asymmetric.

I thought a Set Position node with Noise in the Offset would do the trick, but it is affecting the mesh and not the individual vertices.

Would love some advice, thanks.

(EDIT: UPDATED PROJECT FILE AND IMAGE)

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/57kazc1dcpjr04ya3veou/GN-Vertice-Shift-How.blend?rlkey=ih68msulxgzmqqp8fxvbj1ij3&dl=0)

[image]

Comment: By plugging the `Float` 'Fac' of your _Noise_ into the `Vector` input to _Map Range_, for any float noise-value **V**, you wind up with a vector **(V,V,V)**. Plug the 'Color' in instead , play with the scale setting  of the _Noise_ itself, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @RobinBetts, it certainly does act differently.  However, it still doesn't affect the individual positions of the vertices.  Any suggestions for how to achieve this?

Comment: Your sphere is small, _Noise_ is smooth. The vertices of your sphere are all catching a similar area of the texture.. you can try increasing the coordinate-scale of your _Noise_ from 5 to say, 20. Depending on what poly-count you can stand in your final crystals, this might not be the most convincing approach.. to get enough variation, you risk folding the meshes up: getting self-intersections. It depends.. a _Voronoi_ might be worth a look. Perhaps edit to illustrate what you want to see in the end, and how this asset is to be used.

Comment: @RobinBetts all great advice, thanks.  Essentially what I'm looking for is a deeper understanding of how to manipulate the individual locations of vertices, using geometry nodes.  Is there a way to sample the position of each vertice somehow, and then affect its position?

Comment: Well,  'Offset'  does kind of do that.. by adding your noise vector to each point's existing position. You could offset by some scale of the points' existing Normals?  That would be Noise Fac, again, multiplied by some number, into Vector Math > Scale, with Normal as the vector input, into Offset, again..

Comment: @RobinBetts that's a great idea actually, I will try that